# Getting parameter on 401 (Authorization Required) page Force.com site

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites

We have public visualforce page that hosted on Force.com. It contains wizard with few steps. Sometimes we get an Authorization Required error on the steps. I want to store the fact of displaying Authorization Required page in the record by passing parameter or somehow else. Because right now I don't have any analytics how many users saw it.

Is that possible?

Comment: I wish I had a definitive answer but I think that would depend on the type of error it is. If it is a VF error (which I suspect it is) I don't think there is anything you can do. If it is an Apex error, then you could do a try/catch but there's a chance that the record you try to update will also end up with the same error.

Comment: @gNerb i'm thinking about using cookies. So I can set it on the wizard and get on error page.